# How to unit test Task.run() in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

This question is asked before but not answered.
I want to test Authentication method, where we are checking authorized users from DB which if not Null will return the details of the user. How can I unit test this? I am using Xunit.

```
public async Task<User> Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = await Task.Run(() => _users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == username
                                            && x.Password == password));
        // return null if user not found
        if (user == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new User
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            Username = user.Username,
            Password = ""
        };
    }
```

_user is a list.

Comment: What are you wanting to actually test for?

Comment: Why do you need `Task.Run` in he first place?

Comment: it's legacy. I didn't write it and cant change it

Comment: Then you just make your test method async  inject `_users` in your class and check that `await Authenticate` returns expected stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task.Run is just a detail; going by the code block the test cases would probably be:

- SingleOrDefault returns null
- SingleOrDefault returns a single user

There is no exception handling but that could be another test you may want to do.

If you wanted to introduce a delay when SingleOrDefault is invoked to flex the await you have there, you'd probably have to think about mocking _users so you can introduce that behaviour. I don't think you necessarily need to though, Task.Run will still execute the delegate and provide a result, delay or not. If you did want to persist with it, SingleOrDefault will be an extension so you'd end up mocking the underlying LINQ provider to do this which any of the popular mocking frameworks can do as part of the return value callback.

Finally your xUnit test method may need to be decorated to handle the async SUT.